# Proof that only a homogenous ellipsoid can be uniformly magnetized?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, magnetostatics

Poisson proved that in a paramagnetic material an uniform external field induces uniform magnetization (and uniform internal field) *if* the body has the shape of an ellipsoid, see, e.g., Stratton Chapter 3.

My question is if this result has been **proven** to be unique; in other words, is it true that an uniform external field induces uniform magnetization *if and only if* the body is an ellipsoid? (Of course, the same question can be asked about electrically polarized bodies, as well.)

Comment: The OP in another post mentioned an article (that is behind a paywall) entitled [ Unique shape of uniformly polarizable dielectrics ["Unique shape of uniformly polarizable dielectrics" by K R Brownstein](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1987JMP....28..978B/abstract) which claims to prove this, but I have not been able to access a copy (i.e. outside a paywall).

Comment: A link to the above document's abstract page : [The depolarization field in polarizable objects of general shape" by A. Zehe and A. Ramírez](http://www.scielo.org.mx/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S0035-001X2002000500006&lang=en)